# java ThreadLocal proplem

Tags: java, tomcat

```
private HttpServletRequest request;
private static ThreadLocal<WebContext> wcHolder = new ThreadLocal<WebContext>();
    private WebContext(){}

    public static WebContext newInstance(HttpServletRequest request){
//case 1:correct
//        WebContext wc = new WebContext();
//        wc.request = request;

//case 2：incorrect
//（to resolve multiply creat WebContext object within one request）
        WebContext wc = wcHolder.get();
        if(wc==null){
            wc = new WebContext();
            wc.request = request;
            wcHolder.set(wc);
        }
        return wc;
    }
```

case 1 is correct.

but case 2

1. first tomcat request..
2. second request may get the WebContext object which belong to first req.
3. when step 2 happened，WebContext's request object had diabled.
4. then problem happened when operate on the wc and the request object！

the question is:

1. is one ThreadLocal bind on Thread not right?
2. is one tomcat request is one Thread not right?
3. how correct above code ?

ps:sorry,my english is bad. ：）

Comment: Seeing code that captures a reference to an `HttpServletRequest` leads me to believe that, very soon, you will be posting a question about why your application is behaving strangely, usually confusing a response for one request as another. Be *very* careful when capturing a reference to a `request` object somewhere like a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: yes，you are right.the problem had happened ,when refresh page repeatly,because  get previous request obj by threadLocal.get(). i guess tomcat just assign the same thread for the repeatly browser request that moment.then app throw nullpoint error,i invoke request.getSession().getAtt..

Comment: thanks@John Bollinger,@Christopher Schultz.now the problem had resolved. invoke WebContext.reset(),then method do ThreadLocal.remove(), within spring interceptor.preHandle method.ps thanks more patient for my bad english.i am try better.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. is one ThreadLocal bind on Thread not right?

A `ThreadLocal` binds a separate object to each thread, yes.  That's its purpose.

> 2. is one tomcat request is one Thread not right?

Each request is handled by exactly one thread, but I'm fairly certain that Tomcat does not spawn a new thread for each request.  It uses a thread pool.

Also, different requests in the same session may be served by different threads.

> 3. how correct above code ?

If the previous answers don't explain it then I don't know, because it's not clear in what way you consider the behavior you observe to be incorrect.

Nevertheless, if your intent is for each request to have exactly one `WebContext`, unique to it, then  `ThreadLocal`s seem a poor choice for managing that.  Request attributes, on the other hand, are designed for exactly that purpose.  See [ServletRequest.getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)), [ServletRequest.setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), *etc.*.